# Print Value from specific index in backward

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs. First input `#index` value can be used to target specific index in `Array`. Second input `#length` value can be used to print how many numbers of items we want.

[image]

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] // can have more or less items
```

I want to use `index` to get the expected output but not able to get the logic where to put in code.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

$('button').click(function() {
  var index = $('#index').val();
  var length = $('#length').val();
  var newItems = []
  for (var i = arr.length; i > (arr.length - length); i--) {
    console.log(i)
    newItems.push(arr[i - 1])
  }
  console.log(newItems)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="">1-9 only</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="index" placeholder="index" />
  <input type="text" id="length" placeholder="lengh" />
  <button>Print</button>
</div>
```

So expected output would be

```
// Input
#index  - 1
#length - 1 

// output [9]

// Input
    #index  - 1
    #length - 2 

    // output [9,8]

// Input
    #index  - 9
    #length - 2 

    // output [8,7]

// Input
    #index  - 3
    #length - 5 

    // output [2,1,9,8,7]
```

Comment: You never use `index` anywhere in your code, so it always starts at the end.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that's I want to know where to put it

Comment: Don't you think it should be used to get the starting index of the `for` loop?

Comment: index = 8, length = 2, o/p = [9 8]. Is it correct? Here I am considering index 0 means last item, index 1 means second last item, so on...

Comment: index = 8, length =2, output = [7,6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` and subtract from the starting index:

```js
const mod = (num, n) => ((num % n) + n) % n;
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const printReverse = (startIndex, length) => (
  console.log(
    Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => arr[mod(7 + startIndex - i, arr.length)])
  )
);

printReverse(1, 1);
printReverse(1, 2);
printReverse(9, 2);
printReverse(3, 5);
printReverse(1, 12);
```

Comment: When length is greater then Array length it is printing undefined printReverse(1, 12);

Comment: Add a modulo function that returns positive/zero numbers and not negative numbers, see edit

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

$('button').click(function() {
  var index = $('#index').val();
  var length = $('#length').val();
  var newItems = [];
  var pos = (index + arr.length - 2) % arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++, pos = (pos + arr.length - 1) % arr.length) {
    newItems.push(arr[pos])
  }
  console.log(newItems)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="">1-9 only</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="index" placeholder="index" />
  <input type="text" id="length" placeholder="lengh" />
  <button>Print</button>
</div>
```

Comment: with index 1 and length 19. it is adding undefined

Comment: yeah ... it would do that :p

Comment: @Carlos - refactored code should work - your original problem description never suggested `length` could be more than `arr.length`

Comment: I don't know :p ...it's actually (arr.length - 2) ... index 1 means you start at array index 8, index 3 you start at array index 1 (= (3 + 7) % 9) ... it's your logic :p - I've just edited the code to be array length agnostic - so if you have only 5 array items, the logic should work still